# How do i rewrite path field in views-view-fields.html.twig inside a href tag?

Tags: views, theming, 8

i would like to rewrite the value of my view's path field in views-view-fields.html.twig template. I tried the following and the link is messed up.

```
<a href="{{ fields.path.content }}" alt="">{{ fields.title.content }}</a>
```

my guess is it needs to be written with some type of filter combination and i looked everywhere and can only find examples on how to do this in a node.html.twig file but not in views templates. would somebody kindly advise on how to write this? Many thanks!

Comment: What kind of field is path? e.g., a Link or Text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because `{{ fields.path.content }}` actually is `<div class="something">/your/path</div>` and not just `/your/path`

So try with `<a href="{{ fields.path.content|striptags }}" alt="">`

If the above does not work

Try `<a href="{{ fields.path.content|raw }}" alt="">`

---

Another possibility is that if you have Twig Debug turned on, this will screw up your template. Turning the twig debug off will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having a related problem which was that the theme debugging was polluting my path value. The |striptags allows me to keep my debugging enabled (on my dev site only of course). Where are these pipe options documented? Are there other ones besides striptags and raw?

Comment: Check out the **Filters** and **Functions** from the **[Official Twig Docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/#reference)** You can use those any time you want/need.

Comment: Also, Drupal has it's own filters. See **[Drupal Specific Filters](https://www.drupal.org/node/2357633)**

Comment: I tested both options and the one that works is `<a href="{{ fields.path.content|striptags }}" alt="">my link</a>` even with twig debugging turned on. Thanks No Sssweat.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add several filters to the field, like mentioned here: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2672656#comment-12091013

```
<a href="{{ fields.path.content|render|striptags|trim }}" alt="">{{ fields.title.content|render|striptags|trim }}</a>
```